# Why "Iterator from different contaniner are used together" CppCheck error appear?

Tags: c++, iterator, cppcheck

In my code I have the CppCheck error *"Iterator 'it' from different container 'polyline' are used together"*.

Do you understand why it appears at the line with `.erase(it)` please ?

```
for (QList<QPointF> &polyline : _polylinesPoints) {
        // Start loop with 2nd element and finish it before last element.
        for (auto it = polyline.begin() + 1; it < polyline.end() - 1;) {
            if (*it != newP1 && *it != newP2 && DesignUtils::areCollinear(*(it - 1), *it, *(it + 1)))
                it = polyline.erase(it); --> message here
            else
                ++it;
        }
    }
```

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuoVA.png)

I have a solution with an iterator based for loop, but I would like to understand why this error appears while my code seems to work when I test it.

My solution is:

```
for (auto itPolyline = _polylinesPoints.begin(); itPolyline != _polylinesPoints.end(); ++itPolyline) {
        // Start loop with 2nd element and finish it before last element.
        for (auto it = itPolyline->begin() + 1; it < itPolyline->end() - 1;) {
            if (*it != newP1 && *it != newP2 && DesignUtils::areCollinear(*(it - 1), *it, *(it + 1)))
                it = itPolyline->erase(it);
            else
                ++it;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Baptiste

Comment: This seems like a bug in (unknown to me) tool cppcheck - assuming the code you are showing here matches the actual code which triggers the error, you might want to file a bug to it's maintainers.

Comment: I would say false positive from cppCheck

Comment: @MikeVine what's suspicious about it?

Comment: `_polylinesPoints`'s type is secret?  A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont `_polylinePoints` is a QList<QList<QPointF>>.